# Double comparison - numeric limits

Tags: c++

I have some trouble understanding the following code:

```
double a = -1000;
double b = numeric_limits<double>::min();

if (a < b)
{
   cout << "why?";
}
```

And the output is:

> why?

How can `-1000` be lower than `numeric_limits<double>::min()`?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min notice the mention of `lowest` there in contrast to `min()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because `numeric_limits<double>::min();` is the lowest positive number expressible in double floating-point precision, not the most negative number.